# Functional Programming in Scala - Building the Option Type

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm working through Functional Programming in Scala (first edition) and coming across an error when working through a solution to the first exercise in Chapter 4: Handling errors without exceptions.

The chapter rebuilds the Option type using the following structure:

```
sealed trait Option[+A]
case class Some[+A](get: A) extends Option[A] 
case object None extends Option[Nothing]
```

The first exercise instructs the reader to implement the following methods on the Option type:

```
trait Option[+A] {
def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B]
def flatMap[B](f: A => Option[B]): Option[B] 
def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): B
def orElse[B >: A](ob: => Option[B]): Option[B] 
def filter(f: A => Boolean): Option[A]
}
```

When loading the solution [verified by the answer key for the book](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/second-edition/answerkey/errorhandling/01.answer.scala) via the scala REPL

```
sealed trait Option[+A] {
  def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] = this match {
    case Some(a) => Some(f(a))
    case None    => None
  }
}
case class Some[+A](get: A) extends Option[A]
case object None extends Option[Nothing]
```

I receive a compilation error:

```
scala> :load ErrorHandling.scala
val args: Array[String] = Array()
Loading ErrorHandling.scala...

           case Some(a) => Some(f(a))
                ^
ErrorHandling.scala:3: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
        found   : Some[A(in class Some)]
        required: Option[A(in trait Option)]

           case Some(a) => Some(f(a))
                               ^
ErrorHandling.scala:3: error: type mismatch;
        found   : Some[B]
        required: Option[B]

           case None    => None
                ^
ErrorHandling.scala:4: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
        found   : None.type
        required: Option[A]

           case None    => None
                           ^
ErrorHandling.scala:4: error: type mismatch;
        found   : None.type
        required: Option[B]
```

Given None and Some extend Option, I'm not sure where the type mismatch is arising.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems to work fine in [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/NfseQwgjSNumAbtSm3J8NQ).

Comment: Another suggestions - Don't learn Scala by using REPL. This thing has many instances where it behaves very differently then actual Scala application. Use REPL only for very basic experiments.

Comment: @sarveshseri Good to note... what would be your preferred avenue? Calling methods through a main method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:load` interprets lines in the file one-by-one, as if they were typed. This breaks your case horribly because the lines you type into the REPL act as if they were all in different files; in particular, earlier lines cannot see later ones. So the `Some` and `None` in the definition of `Option` are resolved to the standard ones, not the ones defined later, and `sealed` makes those definitions illegal because they are not in the same "file."

Use `:paste`

```
scala> :paste ErrorHandling.scala
Pasting file ErrorHandling.scala...
trait Option
class Some
object None

scala>
```